# OpenGL ES 1 clipping object

Tags: c, mobile, opengl-es, clipping

I'm fairly inexperienced with OpenGLES1, but I'm forced to use it based on the constraints of what I'm currently working on.

The effect I'm trying to create is a "container" of sorts. 
Example:
[image: Example]

So I'd like to be able to have the objects "frame" clip the object inside the frame. The issue is that the frame is not a perfect square, so I can't just re-size and adjust the texture co-ords.

Some of my peers suggest using stenciling, however I've only ever dealt with that once and I'm not sure the best approach to create a stencil based on the "frame" alpha.

Is there a resource you gentlemen could point me towards? It would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Xoorath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the rendering of the objects that you want clipped within a non-rectangular region then creating a stencil buffer as per the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm) is probably what you need (see section 10.030).

Otherwise, if you want to clip objects (by modifying their coordinates), and not just mask out a region when rendering, then you'll need a polygon clipping library.

Regarding polygon clipping libraries, there are a number of options, but they reduce to one - [GPC](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/) - if you want a library that will compile in C (and not C++). However GPC's license may be problematic to you since it's not free for commercial uses. If the license is a problem, you could consider a number of other libraries if you encapsulated their functionality within a dynamic linked library. These other libraries written in C++ include - [Clipper](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php), [Boost Polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm) and [Boost Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. These are great tools for what I needed.